# JavaScript: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list while add rows with an onchange event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting the error with this JavaScript, I need to do is dynamically add rows with `onchange` of drop down list. ie, Each click on 'Add more' button,add the row and get value on textbox based on the change of drop down menu.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var a = 1;
            $('.tab_new').on('change', '.product_name', function() {
                var product_code = $('#product_name' + a).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: 'price.php',
                    data: {
                        product_code: product_code
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data) {
                            $('#product_price' + a).val(data)
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            $("#add").click(function() {
                a = a + 1;
                $('#datatables tr').eq(-2).after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="client_name[]" value="" id="client_name' + a + '"/></td><td ><select class="product_name" name="product_name[]" id="product_name' + a + '" ><option value=""> --------all-------- </option>  <?php $result=mysql_query("select * from product_form"); while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {   echo "<option value='
                    $row[0]
                    '> $row[1] </option>"; } ?></select></td><td ><input type="number"  name="product_price[]" value=""  id="product_price' + a + '" class=".product_price"/></td></tr>');
            });
        });
HTML:

<table id="dataTables" class="tab_new">
                <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th>CLIENT NAME</th> 
                        <th>PRODUCT NAME </th> 
                        <th>PRICE </th> 
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="client_name[]" value="" id="client_name"/></td>
                        <td><select name="product_name[]" id="product_name1" class="product_name"> 
                                <option value=""> --------ALL-------- </option> 
                                <?php $result=mysql_query("Select * from product_form");
                                     while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                                     { 
                                          echo "<option value='$row[0]'> $row[1] </option>";
                                 } ?>
                        </select></td>
                        <td><input type="number"  name="product_price[]" value=""  id="product_price1" class="product_price"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
            <input type="button" id="add" value="Add More" />

 I am getting an error missing argument when i clicked on the button .
```

Comment: Also provide your Html code

Comment: You're trying to print PHP through your JS code. Why?
Also, $row is nowhere defined in the JS scope but is being used as a variabled here.

Comment: Is your PHP outputting newlines in the middle of that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var a=1;
                $('.tab_new').on('change','.product_name', function(){
                    var product_code = $('#product_name'+a).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: 'price.php',
                        data: {product_code:product_code},
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            if(data){
                                $('#product_price'+a).val(data)
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
                $("#add").click(function(){
                    a=a+1;
                    $('#dataTables tr').last().after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="client_name[]" value="" id="client_name'+a+'"/></td><td ><select name="product_name[]" id="product_name'+a+'" class="product_name"><option value=""> --------ALL-------- </option> <?php $result=mysql_query("Select * from product_form");while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){ ?> <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1]; ?> </option> <?php } ?></select></td><td ><input type="number"  name="product_price[]" value=""  id="product_price'+a+'" class="product_price"/></td></tr>');
                }); 
            }); 
        </script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add js file : jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape `$row[0]` in your code.

While I fail to understand why you're trying to print PHP code in JS like this. It won't work. However, you can resolve the above stated error by escaping `$row[0]`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var a = 1;
     $('.tab_new').on('change', '.product_name', function() {
       var product_code = $('#product_name' + a).val();
       $.ajax({
         type: "get",
         url: 'price.php',
         data: {
           product_code: product_code
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
           if (data) {
             $('#product_price' + a).val(data)
           }
         }
       });
     });
     $("#add").click(function() {
       a = a + 1;
       $('#datatables tr').eq(-2).after('<tr><td><input type="text" name="client_name[]" value="" id="client_name' + a + '"/></td><td ><select class="product_name" name="product_name[]" id="product_name' + a + '" ><option value=""> --------all-------- </option>   <?php $result=mysql_query("select * from product_form"); while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {   echo "<option value=\'$row[0]\'> $row[1] </option>"; } ?></select></td><td ><input type="number"  name="product_price[]" value=""  id="product_price' + a + '" class=".product_price"/></td></tr>');
     });
   });
```

Comment: Actually i need is to add rows when click on button, also want to get value on textbox while change the drop down list.

Comment: <td><select name="product_name[]" id="product_name1" class="product_name"> 
<option value=""> --------ALL-------- </option> 
<?php $result=mysql_query("Select * from product_form");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
 { 
  echo "<option value='$row[0]'> $row[1] </option>";
 } ?>
</select></td>   This code is exactly included in the HTML portion. I just apply it to the script. I already try to print PHP code in JS in codeigniter. its work successfully. but cann't apply here.

Comment: It won't work like this. 
You cannot run a php code by injecting it through JS.

Comment: okay. Thanks for your valuable help. Now i able to know that , is it possible to add rows which has onchange drop down menu and get value in textbox. That is i need to add  onchange drop down menu and textfield on each 'add more' button click.

Comment: You could add another question for that. We can discuss it over there.
Let's not make this thread dirty.

Answer (score 0):

```
price.php file in core php

        <?php include('connect.php');
        if(isset($_REQUEST['product_code'])){
            $sql = mysql_query("select * from product_form where product_code =".$_REQUEST['product_code']);
            $res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            echo $res['product_price'];die;
         }
        ?>

        In case of codeigniter, use this code in controller section

        public function get_product()
            {   
                $pro= $this->input->get('product_code');
                $procode=$this->form1_model->get_productcode($pro);
                echo json_encode($procode);
            }
```